# Get related posts from 2 post types same taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I don't know if this is already covered here but i can't find it.

I'm working on a wordpress project with 3 post types: Hotels, Events and restaurants.

They share one taxonomy (zone).

Now what I want is when I create and event with Zone 1, at the bottom of the single event page display: Hotels from Zone 1 and Restaurants from Zone 1.

Is this even possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: I think this article http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75112/query-related-posts-in-a-custom-post-type-by-a-custom-taxonomy wil be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
$args = array(
 'posts_per_page' => -1, //return all posts
 'post_status' => 'publish', //only published posts
 'post_type' => array('hotels', 'restaurants'),
 'tax_query' => array(
    'taxonomy' => 'zone',
    'terms' => 'zone 1'
),
);
$posts = get_posts($args)
```

hope that at least points you in the right direction
have a look at this [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters)

Comment: I can't get this working. This only cover the zone 1 taxonomy and not all taxonomies, correct? If the event is in the zone 2? How can I echo the restaurants and hotels from the same taxonomy in the event we are viewing?

Comment: something like this?

`$zone_terms = get_terms(
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'zone',
    'hide_empty' => true
  )
);
foreach($zone_terms as $zone_term) {
$args = array(
 'posts_per_page' => -1, //return all posts
 'post_status' => 'publish', //only published posts
 'post_type' => array('hotels', 'restaurants'),
 'tax_query' => array(
    'taxonomy' => 'zone',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => '$zone_term->term_id'
),
);
$posts = get_posts($args)
}`

Comment: Im not sure how you would break this out onto seperate pages though